# React Native Android Studio Emulator launch issue

Tags: react-native

When I try to start my react-native init project with this command `npx react-native start`  nothing happens in the emulator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNANd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command   `npx react-native start` is for starting up the bundler (Metro)
to run it on an android emulator or device you need `npx react-native run-android`.
Before that please make sure you have either a real device connected or an emulator ready. 
You can follow or check by using [this guide](https://medium.com/@deepak.gulati/running-react-native-app-on-the-android-emulator-11bf309443eb) for your Android environment setup.